# How to include my *.jasper files together with *.class files in maven build?

Tags: java, maven, build, jasper-reports

I have a web project that was compiled by ANT. The `*.jasper` files were compiled with the `*.class` files. Once migrated to MAVEN they ceased to be integrated with the build.

I tried to include these file using the *resource* maven tag, but it seems that only include files that are in the resource. How do I tell maven to put them together (in the same folder) with the `*.class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a maven plugin for Jasper. I haven't used this myself but this should be exactly what you need
https://github.com/alexnederlof/Jasper-report-maven-plugin

Follow the usage instructions

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.alexnederlof</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                        <goal>jasper</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jasper</outputDirectory>                    
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And you should be good!

**Update**
Sounds like you have some config needs, to change your source directory

```
 <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/main/java/</source>
                </sources>
  <outputDirectory>(same as your java output)</outputDirectory>     
    </configuration>
```

I believe this will help you out!

Comment: It's fail. I need to distribute the jasper files together class files. This plugin store the jasper files in a specific folder.

Comment: So are you saying that your jasper files are in your output directory (with compiled classes?). That seems odd, if they were with your source (.java) files that would probably be more reasonable. Since they are with compiled output I would think you'd have to run the task AFTER compilation is complete?

Comment: Or are you saying you want your compiled reports in the class directory? if so that should be as simple as specifying the output directory as seen in the config example

Comment: I need to store my *.jasper files together with my *.class files during the building. In design time, these files (jasper) are together with sourcecode java.

Comment: I think you'd just need to change the configuration, updated answer to reflect config details

Comment: But I've a lot of jasper files in many folders... what I should put in outputDirectory tag?

Comment: and more: during the building, show me the follow message: "Execution default of goal com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin:1.6:jasper failed: jasperreports is not a directory"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37747/discussion-between-dellasavia-and-kentonue)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this link: https://bowerstudios.com/node/976

In configuration tag, i put the tag:

```
<sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>
```

And works fine!

Thanks a lot